# how can i plug the DirectJNgine 2.2 into my pom.xml

Tags: extjs

I am kind of new to the maven.

Just wondering how can I plugin DirectJNgine 2.2 into pom.xml file so I can download it from somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should install the artefact in your local repository via maven :

```
> mvn install:install-file -DgroupId=com.softwarementors.extjs -DartifactId=directjngine -Dversion=2.2 -Dpackaging=jar -Dfile=./directjngine.jar

Then, in your pom.xml, add the dependencies for directjngine :

<!-- directjngine deps -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.softwarementors.extjs</groupId>
        <artifactId>directjngine</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.yahoo.platform.yui</groupId>
        <artifactId>yuicompressor</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>rhino</groupId>
        <artifactId>js</artifactId>
        <version>1.6R7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
        <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1</version>
    </dependency>

Happy ext direct coding ;-)
```